# Confidence intervals for model prediction

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am following along with a [statsmodels tutorial](http://github.com/jseabold/tutorial)

An OLS model is fitted with

```
formula = 'S ~ C(E) + C(M) + X' 
lm = ols(formula, salary_table).fit()
print lm.summary()
```

Predicted values are provided through:

`lm.predict({'X' : [12], 'M' : [1], 'E' : [2]})`

The result is returned as a single value array.

Is there a method to also return confidence intervals for the predicted value (prediction intervals) in statsmodels?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you google "python statsmodels confidence"?

Comment: Yes, I looked at that. It returns the CI of the fitted values in the model results summary. I was looking for CI of predicted values. Essentially I am looking for 95% CI's of Y_hat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We've been meaning to make this easier to get to. You should be able to use

```
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.predstd import wls_prediction_std
prstd, iv_l, iv_u = wls_prediction_std(results)
```

If you have any problems, please file an issue on github.

Comment: Thanks @jseabold. I knew it had to be feature somewhere.

Comment: Is there a way to get prediction intervals also for NEW data predicted by the model?
The method quoted here returns prediction intervals just for training data.

Comment: @MarcoMene the `wls_prediction_std()` accept a second argument, `exog` which can be NEW data.

Answer (score 0):

additionally you can try to use the get_prediction method.

```
values_to_predict = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [12], 'M' : [1], 'E' : [2]})
predictions = result.get_prediction(values_to_predict)
predictions.summary_frame(alpha=0.05)
```

I found the summary_frame() method buried [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/987#issuecomment-133575422) and you can find the get_prediction() method [here](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.get_prediction.html). You can change the significance level of the confidence interval and prediction interval by modifying the "alpha" parameter.