# How to compute Prediction Intervals for Machine Learning Regression Tasks in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

Iam quite new to the field of ML and DS and currently I am struggling since 2 days with the basic idea of illustrating the uncertainty of my prediction. I constructed an ensemble model based on several weak learners and an xgboost as meta learner to predict the the expected payment date of an invoice for a given period of time (e.g. 1 month) and thus to compute the expected cash-in for this period. The outcome (expected payment days) are not normally distributed.

Now I am struggling with the idea of showing the uncertainty of my prediction. I read a lot about Confidence Intervals (CI) and Prediction Intervals(PI) and due to my understanding, PI should be the way to go. I want to achieve something like the built-in function in statsmodels.ARIMA or the prophet package:
[image]

How can I calculate the Prediction Intervals for my predictions on the test set and for the new unseen data in Python?

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the text

Comment: Q1 is off-topic (not a programming one), Q2 is too broad, and Q3 is again off-topic  (recommendation request) - please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Q2: What do you exactly mean with too broad? I cant give you a minimal working solution since I am looking for a starting point to even compute this one. The question directly indicates what I am currently looking for: A method to calculate the prediction intervals for the test data as well as for new unseen data points to illustrate the uncertainty of the prediction.

Comment: Check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248013/confidence-intervals-for-model-prediction

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but maybe useful for other.

```py
# Function for prediction interval
def get_prediction_interval(prediction, y_test, test_predictions, pi=.95):

      '''
        Get a prediction interval for a linear regression.

        INPUTS: 
            - Single prediction, 
            - y_test
            - All test set predictions,
            - Prediction interval threshold (default = .95) 
        OUTPUT: 
            - Prediction interval for single prediction
        '''
      #get standard deviation of y_test
      sum_errs = np.sum((y_test - test_predictions)**2)
      stdev = np.sqrt(1 / (len(y_test) - 2) * sum_errs)

      #get interval from standard deviation
      one_minus_pi = 1 - pi
      ppf_lookup = 1 - (one_minus_pi / 2)
      z_score = stats.norm.ppf(ppf_lookup)
      interval = z_score * stdev

      #generate prediction interval lower and upper bound
      lower, upper = [ i - interval for i in prediction], [ i + interval for i in prediction]

      return lower, upper


lower_bound, upper_bound = get_prediction_interval(grid.best_estimator_.predict(X_train),
                        y_train, grid.best_estimator_.predict(X_train))
```

after that you can show it in plot.

```py
plt.fill_between(
    model.predict(X_test),
    lower, upper,
    color="tab:orange",
    alpha=0.5,
    label=r"95% confidence interval",
)
```